# ECONNRESET Aborted error randomly during node process

Tags: node.js, tcp, axios, discord.js

My node js application ( a discord bot ) keeps crashing with the `Error: aborted` message and code `ECONNRESET`. I have some some digging and it seems that the issue occurs when the other end of a TCP connection hangs up abruptly.

The error message I always get:

```
Error: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:631:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:438:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at node:net:666:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:573:7) {
code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

As you can see the error message is not very useful and doesn't provide any informatino as to where the error happened. I am getting the error through the node `process.on('uncaughtException', err => {})` exception handler.

I am using discord.js `^12.5.1` node `15.4.0` and axios `^0.21.1` although the error seems to occur randomly and looking through the logs there is never a specific function call that triggers it and sometimes it happens whilst no functions have even been called.

The error happens sporadically as well. Sometimes it happens once a day and other times it will happen 5 times in an hour.

I should also add I am using the Heroku free tier for hosting,

If anyone could shed some light that would be very useful.

Comment: Where are you hosting it?

Comment: On the Heroku free tier. Server location is France.

Comment: I suspect it's probably occurring when the dyno is falling asleep

Comment: I don't think thats the problem as I am using a work dyno which does not fall asleep. Regardless it falls asleep after 30 minutes of inactivity and yesterday it failed with this error 6 times in an hour.

Comment: Are you using anything related to Discord Voice?

Comment: No I am not. [This](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/5202#issuecomment-767386932) discord js issue seems to have a similar issue but is to do with voice. I am using no voice commands at all

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue - I am not using discord js.
have migrated express to fastify framework, upgraded the Axios version, and upgraded Node to 18. Has anyone faced a similar issue with the above stack?